# no-mtab option not working for mount

Tags: rhel, mount, loop-device, etc

I have a script which tries to mount `/dev/loop0` on a mount point, say `/mnt/mp` on RHEL. The command I use is below.

```
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/mp --no-mtab -o ro
```

This is not supposed to create any entry in `/etc/mtab`. This works OK till RHEL 6 but on RHEL 7 this commands adds the entry in `/etc/mtab`. What might be the reason? How can I suppress it on RHEL 7?

Comment: One workaround may be to use the [unshare](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html) program to create a shell session with its own private mount namespace.

Answer (score 3):

On modern systems, /etc/mtab is a symbolic link to /proc/mounts.  /proc/mounts is a virtual file provided by the kernel which shows the current status of all mounts.  Therefore `/proc/mounts` will always be updated after any `mount` operation.  See `man mount`.

> The programs mount and umount traditionally maintained a list  of  cur‐
>          rently  mounted filesystems in the file /etc/mtab.  This real mtab file
>          is still supported, but on current Linux systems it is better  to  make
>          it a symlink to /proc/mounts instead, because a regular mtab file main‐
>          tained in userspace cannot reliably work  with  namespaces,  containers
>          and other advanced Linux features.

RHEL7 appears to be such a system.

> It  is  possible  that files /etc/mtab and /proc/mounts don't match
>
> ...
>
> use kernel (/proc/mounts) as a source about filesystems information. This solution will be used in RHEL7.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=751691#c1>

Comment: Thanks @sourcejedi. Can we consider that --no-mtab option is deprecated ? If not, how can this be used ?

Comment: @Durgesh "real mtab file is still supported" by mount (from util-linux). However your distribution might not support replacing the symlink the distribution created.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend this because things that read /etc/mtab might break, but you could do:

```
# cd /etc
# rm mtab
# touch mtab.real
# ln -s mtab.real mtab
# reboot
```

systemd does not appear to update mtab so it remains empty.